# Unlink Not Removing File

Tags: c++, c++11, recursion, unlink

Trying to understand why unlink isn't working (not removing the file) in my code down below. The only thing I can imagine is that the program thinks I'm still interacting with the file so its not actually unlinking it since its still in use. The code is meant to be a copy of "rm"

```
void directorySearch(const char *dName)
{
        DIR *dir;
        struct dirent *ent;
        if ((dir = opendir (dName)) != NULL)
        {
                while ((ent = readdir (dir)) != NULL)
                {

                        if ( ent->d_type!=DT_DIR)
                        {
                                //Where the crazy happens
                                printf ("%s\n", ent->d_name);
                                char path[PATH_MAX];
                                const char * d_name = ent->d_name;
                                unlink(path);
                        }
                        if ( ent->d_type==DT_DIR && strcmp(ent->d_name, ".")!= 0 && strcmp(ent->d_name, "..") != 0)
                        {
                                int path_length;
                                char path[PATH_MAX];
                                const char * d_name = ent->d_name;

                                path_length = snprintf (path, PATH_MAX, "%s/%s", dName, d_name);

                                directorySearch(path);
                        }
                }
                closedir (dir);
        }
        else
        {
                cout << "error with "<< dName<< endl;
        }
}
```

Edited with unlink instead of remove, although both don't work...

Comment: Define _isn't working_.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius Just noticed that I still have "remove(path)" instead of unlink since I was just looking for any change. But the calls aren't removing the files in my test directories.

Comment: Are you sure the call is succeeding? I don't see any error checking done in your code, in regards to `unlink` call.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius Yeah, placing error checks would probably be the smart thing to do. The assignment is due tomorrow morning and was trying to rush through. I'll work on throwing some error checks and see if it gives me anything helpful.

Comment: You never put anything into `path` before calling `unlink()`.

Comment: Thank you so much @Barmar !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have declared your path variable, but not actually copied anything into that variable.  So that's a problem.  Also, as a matter of course you should examine the return value from unlink, and if less than zero, examine errno to determine the exact nature of the error.  (Typically permissions on no such file.)

Comment: Waaaaaaah, thanks for pointing that out! Thanks to everyone else, shouldn't try and procrastinate so much and use error checking more.